# Getting error in AJAX response in Laravel Blade Template

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am getting error in my AJAX response.

I am trying to view a specific patient details while clicking 'view' button from 'All Patient' table using AJAX request.

But getting error in response like below image
[image]

But I returned an 'id' from my controller.

**AJAX**

```
$(".view_prescription").click(function(){
                var id = $(this).val();
                var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

                $.ajax({
                   type:'GET',
                   url:'/view-prescription',
                   data:{
                       _token : "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                       id: id
                   },
                   success:function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                   }
                });
            });
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/view-prescription','PrescriptionController@view_prescription');
```

**Controller**

```
public function view_prescription(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        return $id;
    }
```

I understand that it's a slight mistake. But I can't figure that. Anybody help please

Comment: You must return a view or `echo` some data.

Comment: Do you have any other route that might catch that url?

Comment: @Jerodev....... NO. route name is unique

Comment: Sorry for trying to help

Comment: @AnkurTiwari....the given image is my response. That's my error I mean actually

Comment: @u_mulder....Yes now work perfectly. But I have already use 'return' in my another project for AJAX response. There was no error.

Comment: try `return response($request->id,200);`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

just change url from '/view-prescription' to "{{url('/view-prescription')}}" and comment our 'token'.

```
$(".view_prescription").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            //var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

            $.ajax({
               type:'GET',
               url:"{{url('/view-prescription')}}",
               data:{
                   _token : "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                   id: id
               },
               success:function(data) {
                  alert(data);
               }
            });
        });
```